# servers for android app to save and share user data - does their exist a service?

Tags: android, database, backup, share, public

I want to use a database on a web service which supports user management, public tables and private tables.

My use case is, that I want users to save their data in this public table and to share some data with all other app users.

I would solve that with a web page with php and reading and writing JSON objects to a database.

But before, I wanted to know if their exists a service that I could use for that.... So that I don't have to write a complete homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parse**

> Parse handles everything you need to store data securely and
> efficiently in the cloud. Store basic data types, locations, photos,
> and query across them in just a few lines of code.

Pricing: Free < 15 million request a month otherwise 199$ month

https://parse.com/products/data

**Stackmob**

> The StackMob platform lets you build applications using data from any
> cloud or behind the firewall, so you can get to market faster than
> ever. The platform has the features to build any application, but the
> platform is not an island; we’ve engineered it to work with countless
> third party services and data sources.

Pricing: Free, pro plans with extra features

https://www.stackmob.com/product/

**Kinvey**

> User management: Add any number of users, using the authentication
> systems of your choice. You can use Kinvey, Facebook, Twitter, Google,
> LinkedIn and any other OAuth2 authentication provider.
>
> Data storage: Instantly and securely sync data between your app and Kinvey backend.
> Your data is stored on the device or browser, ensuring content remains
> available even when your user is offline.

Pricing: Free to start, pay per 100(0) users. Upgrade for extra storage space or "free users"

http://www.kinvey.com/developer/features

Comment: Sounds interesting, I will check them out... Any personal recommendation?

Comment: I like Parse the best. Clean interface, good documentation. And I am am far away from the 15 million requests, so it's free to.